# Initial value for Django form field when using custom template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

There is a BooleanField in my Django form that I would like to have an initial value of True, so I defined it as:

```
my_checkbox = forms.BooleanField(label='My Checkbox', help_text='Some help text here', initial=True)
```

In my helper, I have:

```
helper.layout = Layout(
    Field('my_checkbox', template="custom.html")
```

Custom.html looks like:

```
<input class="checkboxinput" id="id_{{ field.name }}" name="{{ field.name }}" type="checkbox">
<span id="hint_id_{{ field.name }}" class="help-inline">{{ field.help_text }}</span>
```

I tried outputting the value of field.initial, but nothing shows up.  I know that if I were coding this manually, I would just put `<input ... checked>`, and the box would be checked.

Is there some way to access the "initial" part of the field and set it in my custom template?  Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can access the initial data of the form field using

```
{{field.value}}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the user has not yet selected a value (the form is unbound).

Comment: It does work for me (in Django 1.6) on an unbound form, while `{{ field.initial }}` doesn't.

Comment: Actually it works. If like me you're passing the form object to the template you need to use `{{ form.field.value}}`, and not `{{ form.data.field.value }}` or `{{ form.cleaned_data.field.value }}`.

Answer (score -1):

It really is {{ field.initial }} on unbound forms.  To manually render the form's initial value on a radio button, for example:

```html
{% for value, descr in field.choices %}
  <input type="radio" name="{{ field.html_hame }}" value="{{ value }}"{% if field.initial == value %} checked{% endif %}>{{ descr }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```